# Mapping circles via inversion in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Consider two unshaded circles $C_r$ and $C_s$ with radii $r>s$ that touch at the origin of the complex plane. The shaded circles $C_1,C_2...C_7$ (labeled in counterclockwise direction sequentially) all touch $C_r$ internally and $C_s$ externally. $C_1$ also touches the real axis and $C_i$ and $C_{ i+1}$ touch for $i=1...6.$

Let $r_i$ denote the radius of $C_i$. Then show that for $i=1,2...,$ 
$$r_i^{-1} + 3r_{i+2}^{-1} = 3r_{i+1}^{-1} + r_{i+3}^{-1}$$

A picture is attached for clarity.

[image]

Attempt:

Under inversion, $C_s$ and $C_r$ are mapped to lines and $C_i, i \in \left\{1,...,6\right\}$ are mapped to circles. The map $f(z) = 1/z$ is conformal, so the angles are preserved wherever $f'(z) \neq 0$. Each circle has $4$ tangent points, (except $C_7$) so under the transformation these $\pi/2$ angles are preserved.

The resulting image I have after the transformation is that the $C_i$ are mapped to circles that lie within the two lines and touch the sides.   The only way I see just now to preserve the angles is to have all the circles of the same radii. If $s$ is the radius of $C_s$ and $r$ the radius of $C_r$ then the centre between these two lines is $\frac{1}{2}\left(1/s - 1/2r\right) $. (But I do not think this makes sense.)

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two circles $C_r$ and $C_s$ are mapped to the parrallel lines $\left\{ \operatorname{Re} w = \frac{1}{2r}\right\}$ and $\left\{ \operatorname{Re} w = \frac{1}{2s}\right\}$ by the inversion. Since the inversion maps circles to circles (where a straight line is counted as a circle of infinite radius), it maps each of the $C_i$ to a circle touching both of these parallel lines. Also, the image of $C_1$ touches the real axis (since $C_1$ does, and the inversion maps the real axis $\cup \{\infty\}$ to itself), and further, each circle $C_k$ for $k > 1$ touches the circles $C_{k-1}$ and $C_{k+1}$, hence so do their images.

The distance between the two parallel lines is $\frac{1}{2s} - \frac{1}{2r}$, so the images of the $C_k$ have the common radius

$$R = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2s} - \frac{1}{2r}\right),$$

and their centres all lie on the line $$\left\{ \operatorname{Re} w = M\right\};\qquad M := \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2s} + \frac{1}{2r}\right).$$

It follows that the centre of the image $C_k'$ of $C_k$ is

$$b_k = M - (2k-1)\cdot iR,$$

and hence the defining equation of $C_k'$ is

$$\lvert w-b_k\rvert^2 = R^2,$$

or

$$w\overline{w} - b_k\overline{w} - \overline{b_k}w + (\lvert b_k\rvert^2 - R^2) = 0.$$

Applying the inversion, we see that $C_k$ has the defining equation

$$1 - b_k z - \overline{b_kz} + (\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2)z\overline{z} = 0.$$

Since $\lvert b_k\rvert^2 = M^2 + (2k-1)^2R^2 > R^2$, we can divide and obtain the equivalent equation

$$z\overline{z} - \frac{\overline{b_k}}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2}\overline{z} - \frac{b_k}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2 - R^2} z + \frac{1}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2} = 0,$$

or

$$\left\lvert z - \frac{\overline{b_k}}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2} \right\rvert^2 = \left(\frac{R}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2}\right)^2.$$

The desired relation between the radii should not be difficult to obtain from that.

Comment: Very nice. Could you explain how you obtained the equation for the centre of the image $C_k'$ and what $R$ represents?

Comment: $R$ is half the distance between the two parallel lines. Since a circle that touches two parallel lines must have its centre half-way between the two lines, that is the radius of such a circle. So that gives us the real part of the centres, and for the imaginary part, we have $(k-1)$ circles between $C_k'$ and the real line, and for the centre, we must go one radius further, so $(2k-1)\cdot R$. And a minus sign, since the inversion maps the upper half-plane to the lower.

Comment: Many thanks, I think your formulae are equivalent to the ones I am given for a general transformation -  For a circle of radius $r$, centered at $z_o$, the image under inversion is also a circle of radius $R$ centered at $w_o$, where $$w_o = \frac{z_o^*}{|z_o|^2 - r^2} and    R = \frac{r}{|z_o|^2 - r^2}$$ In this case, how would I obtain $z_o$?  For sure I can divide both equations, but then I am still left with a $z_o^*$.

Comment: For the circle $C_k'$, we have $z_0 = b_k$. I gave the $b_k$ explicitly, you can just insert that.

Comment: Yes, but $z_o$ is the centre of the circle before the transformation.  In my notation, $w_o = b_k, $not $z_o$.  Or did I misunderstand something? Thanks.

Comment: The situation is symmetric, since the inversion is an involution. Using fitting indices, we have $$z_k = \frac{\overline{b_k}}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2}.$$ Where $R$ is the radius of the $C_k'$.

Comment: Is this not effectively saying that the centre of the image circle is the same as the original circle? (I know this isn't true, but this is what it appears since we can set $z_o = b_k$)

Comment: No. However, the formula to pass from one circle to the other is the same because that transformation mapping the one circle to the other is the same - $z \mapsto 1/z$.

Comment: Okay, so it is just a case of subbing in the values of $R, b_k$ and relabeling $r \rightarrow r_k$ and then manipulating the equation to get the required identity?

Comment: Yes, just plugging in the values.

Comment: One last question, how do we obtain the different indices on the $r_k$. For example, on subbing in I would get only $r_i$ if I let $r \rightarrow r_i$ and not $r_{ i+3}$ say.

Comment: Actually, I think it might simply be a case of doing the computation four times (i.e $r \rightarrow r_i$ and then $r \rightarrow r_{i+1}$ etc..)and explicitly showing the result.  Is that correct?

Comment: Just one computation is necessary. Note that the relation depends on the index in a simple manner, just plug in the values for the corresponding indices (I called them $k$ instead of $i$ to avoid a clash with the imaginary unit).

Comment: So do you mean something like if, say, $r \rightarrow r_k$ and $b_k = M - (2k-1)iR$ then if $r \rightarrow r_{k+1}$, $b_{k+1} = M - (2(k+1)-1)iR$ and then subbing in?

Comment: Exactly that. Then expand a few terms, and you have the relation for arbitrary long chains of circles, no need to stop at $7$.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll try this tomorrow cause it is getting late here. +1 and accepted.

Comment: For each of my expressions $r_{k}, r_{k+1}...$ I ended up with a quadratic in $r_k$. I can then solve this for $r_k$, and invert to give $$r_k^{-1} + 3r_{k+2}^{-1} = \frac{2}{\alpha_1} + \frac{3 \cdot 2}{\alpha_2},$$ where $\alpha_1 = -\frac{1}{R} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{R^2} + 4(M^2+(2k-1)^2R^2}$ and similarly for $\alpha_2$ be replacing $k \rightarrow k+2$.  I don't see how that will give me $r_{ i+1}^{-1} + r_{i+3}^{-1}$ though since the only terms that change is the one with $k$ in the denominator.

Comment: Then we must have misunderstood each other at some point and you didn't mean the same with $r_k$ as I did. You have $$r_k = \frac{R}{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2},$$ and thus, $$r_k^{-1} = \frac{\lvert b_k\rvert^2-R^2}{R},$$ the denominator of $r_k^{-1}$ is independent of $k$, and you have a simple quadratic in $k$ in the numerator.

Comment: What I was using was $$R = \frac{r_k}{|b_k|^2 - r_k^2}$$ which under I think since the map is an involution, to obtain $r_k$, I have that $$r_k = \frac{R}{|b_k|^2 - R^2}$$ Is that correct?  I managed to prove it this way, so thanks for letting me know. The next part of the question is to show that $7r_4^{-1} = 2r_7^{-1} + 5r_{1}^{-1}$ The most obvious approach is to sub in indices into the derived formula, but when I tried this I was going in circles. Is there another approach? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that $R$ and $\lvert b_k\rvert^2$ are the things we know, and we obtain $r_k$ from that. The next identity boils - since $7 = 2+5$ - down to verifying $$7\cdot 7^2 = 2\cdot 13^2 + 5.$$

Comment: Could you explain that a little more? I see that in the equation $7=2+5$, the numbers here are the coefficients of the $r_k$, but I do not see the significance of the $7^2$ or $13^2$ and how it relates to the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Inserting the formula for $r_k$, it becomes $$7\frac{\lvert b_4\rvert^2 - R^2}{R} = 2\frac{\lvert b_7\rvert^2 - R^2}{R} + 5\frac{\lvert b_1\rvert^2-R^2}{R}.$$ Forget the common denominator. The $-R^2$ cancel since $7 = 2+5$, what remains is $$7\lvert b_4\rvert^2 = 2\lvert b_7\rvert^2 + 5\lvert b_1\rvert^2.$$ Insert $\lvert b_k\rvert^2 = M^2 + (2k-1)^2R^2$. The $M^2$ cancel since $7 = 2+5$. Ignore the common factor $R^2$. What remains is $7(2\cdot 4-1)^2 = 2(2\cdot 7-1)^2 + 5(2\cdot 1-1)^2.$

Comment: Thanks, I see now.  I appreciate all the help you have given

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I'm trying to get an idea of the resultant picture after inversion. Is it something like this?

Comment: Hi Alan, that is exactly what I was thinking except shouldn't the circles be tending downwards?

Comment: I am not really sure how to progress to obtain the required identity.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_chain and   here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappusChain.html