# Relationship Between Circles Under Inversion

Tags: complex-analysis

Considering the inversion $w=\frac{1}{z}$
Consider two unshaded circles $C_{r}$ and $C_{s}$ with radii $r>s$ that touch at the origin of the complex plane. The shaded circles $C_{1}$,$C_{2}...C_{7}$ (labeled in counterclockwise direction sequentially) all touch $C_{r}$ internally and $C_{s}$ externally. $C_{1}$ also touches the real axis and $C_{i}$ and $C_{i+1}$ touch for $i=1...6$.

Let $r_{i}$ denote the radius of $C_{i}$. Then show that for $i=1,2...,$
$r^{−1}_{i}+3r^{−1}_{i+2}=3r^{−1}_{i+1}+r^{−1}_{i+3}$.

[image: Problem Diagram]

I'm struggling to begin with this problem. I know that under inversion the two circles touching at the origin $C_{r}$ and $C_{s}$ will be mapped to straight lines and that the other circles will be mapped to circles, however I'm struggling to see how I would obtain the $r^{-1}_{i}$s. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be the same problem as: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674207/mapping-circles-via-inversion-in-the-complex-plane